# Local translations in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, supergravity, poincare-symmetry

A global Poincare transformation on a scalar field induces

$$\delta(a, \lambda)\phi(x) = [a^{\mu}+\lambda^{\mu\nu}x_{\nu}]\partial_{\mu}\phi(x). \tag{11.46}$$

In curved spacetime we replace $a^{\mu} \rightarrow \xi^{\mu}(x)$, but I read that in fact this new spacetime dependent parameter $\xi^{\mu}$ eats up the effect of the "orbital part of global Lorentz", so that in fact $\xi^{\mu}(x)=a^{\mu}(x)+\lambda^{\mu\nu}(x)x_{\nu}$, and we effectively have to treat $\xi^{\mu}$ and $\lambda^{ab}$ (the spin part of Lorentz) as the basis for gauge transformations.

I don't understand why this should be, any comments that might help? Why does the new local translation parameter include the effect of what globally used to be rotations/boosts?

References:

1. D.Z. Freedman & A. Van Proeyen, *SUGRA,* 2012; p. 225.

Answer (score 7):

1. Ref. 1 defines a *local translation* on spacetime $M$ as a *diffeomorphism.*
2. Note that the words *local* and *global* in this physics context mean point-dependent (=$x$-dependent) and point-independent (=$x$-independent), respectively. [Be aware that mathematicians in other contexts typically use the words *local* and *global* to refer to objects defined in a *local* neighborhood $U\subseteq M$, or *globally* on the whole manifold $M$, respectively. Ref. 1 does not dwell on this latter distinction, and implicitly assumes that the definitions of objects can be extended/restricted appropriately, if needed.]
3. An *infinitesimal diffeomorphisms* $\xi^{\mu}(x)$ can be identified with a *vector field.*
4. Note that in flat Minkowski spacetime the *affine transformations* are *global$^1$ Poincare transformations.*  However, Ref. 1 concerns GR and curved spacetime. *Global$^1$ Lorentz transformations,* *global$^1$ Poincare transformations,* and *affine transformations* become obsolete/meaningless notions in GR. Such transformations are all just special cases of *local translations.*
5. On the other hand, in the terminology of Ref. 1, the *local Lorentz transformations* do not denote (and should not be confused with) a subset of diffeomorphisms. Instead a *local Lorentz transformation* $\Lambda^a{}_b(x)$ is a transformations between choices of frames in the tangent bundle. In other words, it transforms the flat indices $a,b,\ldots$, (but not the curved indices $\mu,\nu,\ldots$), of various tensors, e.g. the vielbein $e^a_{\mu}(x)$.
6. Together the *local translations* and *local Lorentz transformations* form the *local Poincare transformations.*
7. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/400085/2451) & [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/225413/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

References:

1. D.Z. Freedman & A. Van Proeyen, *SUGRA,* 2012; p. 225.

--

$^1$ We repeat that the word *global* means here $x$-independent, cf. pt. 2.

Comment: Hello, could you please explain to me why did you say that I quote: "Such transformations are all just special cases of local translations." I didn't quite understand how they are special cases of local translations.