# Why do we use affine groups in gauge theory? What is the purpose?

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-theory, group-theory, poincare-symmetry

When we study General Relativity in the frame of gauge theory, what's the importance of affine group?

Comment: Why do you think the affine group is used in GR?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175297/2451