What does it mean that the symmetry group of General Relativity is the Poincare group?
I know and understand the definition of the Poincare group. What I'm concerned about here is how do we understand that the symmetry group of a Lorentzian manifold is the Poincare group?
I would suggest this can be understood by the language of principal bundles and taking the symmetry group of the bundle to be its gauge/structure group. This by taking the frame bundle of the manifold but as far as I can make it the gauge/structure group is the Lorentz group - where am I going wrong here.
edit
The question that has been linked as a duplicate is not a duplicate of this question. Simply because both posts mention "covariance" and "General Relativity" does not imply that the questions are related. They are different. I am asking how does the symmetry group manifest itself as the gauge/structure group of a principal bundle whereas the linked question does not. I've asked @naturallyInconsistent, who linked the question, to please explain and justify why he/she thought these questions are related? He/she has not replied to my request for clarification.

This question is similar to: Covariance in special and general relativity. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175297/2451 and links therein.

@naturallyInconsistent: Simply because both podts mention "covariance" and "General Relativity" does not imply that the questions are related. They are different. I am asking how does the symmetry group manifest itself as the gauge/structure group of a principal bundle. Can you please explain and justify why you think these questions are related?

@Qmechanic: First see my above comment. Simply because the linked post mentions the "Poincare group" and "curved space" does not imply that my question is related. I'm not interested in the post you are linking to. Can you please explain and justify why you think these posts are related?

"the symmetry group of a Lorentzian manifold is the Poincare group" - Who claims it is? In what context? For various confusing claims about the symmetry groups of general relativity, see e.g. this answer of mine or also this answer of mine (though the latter is somewhat out of date compared to the former and I no longer believe it to be fully correct).
